# shell: evaluate an curl expression

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

In this following script i generate a status code and if the statusCode=200, i send the data else if the statusCode !=200 i générate à token and i send the message by recalling eval "$request_cmd". 
**strong text**
But actually when i did this i get this error "command introuvable" at this line eval "$request_cmd".

```
#!/bin/bash

#variables
randomNumber=$(shuf -i000000-999999 -n1)
eventTime=$(date --rfc-3339=ns | sed 's/ /T/')
idEpc="OneVariable"
fromRecordtime=`date --utc +%FT%T.%3NZ`
goodStatus="200"


printf "\n ---------------------------------> SENDING MESSAGE <-------------------------------------- \n\n"

request_cmd=$(curl -X POST -w "%{http_code}" --http1.0 \
"$1/api/acquire/rabbitmq/epcis" \
-H 'Authorization: Basic YWtytrytrytrytrW46trttrytrytr' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
-H 'Postman-Token: 2c4f9rtertzertertrezatre4' \
-H "X-Authorization: Bearer ${generatedToken}" \
-d 'Here i have the data')
echo $request_cmd

if [ "$request_cmd" != "$goodStatus" ]
then
    printf "\n ---------------------------------> GETTING TOKEN <-------------------------------------- \n\n"
    generatedToken=$(curl -X POST $2/MyURL/token -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret=abesdfsd677c-6dsdfsba-4ddfsc8-978fsdfdsfsb-ec256cf65914&client_id=che-gateway' | jq -r .access_token)
eval "$request_cmd"
echo $request_cmd
```

Comment: `$request_cmd` will be whatever `curl` outputs, not the `curl` command itself.

Comment: I think the phrase _"i send the message by recalling eval "$request_cmd"."_ could do with some clarification. (What message? What do you mean with "recalling eval"?)

Comment: sorry, i try to evaluate  "$request_cmd". when i did this i get error "command introuvable" because this curl command return a statuscode of request

Comment: the message is the data in xml format. i mean call the curl request to send the data

Comment: simply, how can i get the "http code" of an curl request, then send an message with the same curl request

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

> In this following script i generate a status code and if the statusCode=200

That isn't what your code does. It puts both the status code *and* any document that comes back into the variable `$request_cmd`. This might not cause you a problem right now, if the document is empty, but it's a little sloppy.

See https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code

> I send the data else if the statusCode !=200 I generate a token and I send the message by recalling eval "$request_cmd"

This isn't what your code does. Suppose you run the first curl, and you get back something like "401 Unauthorized." eval will try to run the command "401," but there is no command called that.

I think you mean to use [bash functions](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-functions.php) here. You can use a bash function to run the same piece of code multiple times.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
function request_cmd {
status_code=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST -w "%{http_code}" --http1.0 \
"$1/api/acquire/rabbitmq/epcis" \
-H 'Authorization: Basic YWtytrytrytrytrW46trttrytrytr' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
-H 'Postman-Token: 2c4f9rtertzertertrezatre4' \
-H "X-Authorization: Bearer ${generatedToken}" \
-d 'Here i have the data')
echo $status_code
}
request_cmd # calls curl and puts result into $status_code
generatedToken=foo # changes the value of generatedToken
request_cmd # calls curl again with new generatedToken value
```

Comment: Hi Nick ODell, you have exactly understood my problem. i need to call the curl without generating token cause in some environment we don't need to generate a token this i why i use the condition "if status code!=200" we generate à token and retry to send the data with the same curl command.

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem, then?